# How to add a Network scanner Mf4500W

Tags: networking, printing

My system is connected with a Canon-MF4500W-UFRII-LT as network printer? The printer is working good but how can I use this same device for scanning,does I need more drivers for it?

Answer (score 0):

so SANE says it supports your MF4500series devices with good support;

with printers; data leaves the computer; with scanners; data goes 2 ways between scanner and computer; so security issues.

so sadly you need to read this; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo#Sharing_a_Scanner_Over_a_Network

SANE says it supports your MF4500series devices with good support;  and drop some security barriers; to allow data to flow in from the scanner;

please keep in touch; if it is all too hard, we can try to take it step by step

and this next tutorial

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial?action=show&redirect=sane.d+tutorial

takes things to more complex areas; but its part one tells you what is likely to be good for you; (covers ground of previous link)